# Horizontal Alignment GWT VerticalPanel

Tags: java, gwt

VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
panel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);

The above is not left aligning the Tree widget I am adding to this panel.  Any ideas on how I can left align the Tree widget?

Answer (score 2):

i thought that the default alignment for any components is `left` alignment :) (correct me if i'm wrong.) anyways, here it goes:

```
panel.setCellHorizontalAlignment(treeWidget, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
```

and you can also do this in `UiBinder` by:

```
<g:cell horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_LEFT">
   <g:VerticalPanel>
   ...
   </g:VerticalPanel>
</g:cell>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

`panel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT)`;